# How to I initialize a class with an interface button clicked? [Objective - C]

Tags: objective-c, class, button

I am having a problem with figuring out how to initialize a class with button clicked. The code is listed below the line I have a problem with has "HELP NEEDED HERE" comment above it.

```
//
//  Controller.m
//  
#import "Controller.h"

@implementation Controller
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        numberTotal = 0;
        //HELP NEEDED HERE
        [self btnScore_Clicked:(id)sender];
    }
    return self;}
- (IBAction) btnScore_Clicked:(id)sender {
    numberTotal += 1;
    NSLog(@"Number Total: %d",numberTotal);
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
@end

//
//  Controller.h
//  
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Controller : UIViewController {
    NSInteger numberTotal;
}
- (IBAction) btnScore_Clicked:(id)sender;
@end
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean to "initialize a class with an interface button clicked"? Based on the code you've provided, it is equivalent to just writing `if (self) numberTotal = 1;`

Comment: @Chuck, So usually, btnScore_Clicked method is invoked when I press a button. I want to invoke it once, when the Controller class gets created.

Comment: @Chuck, need a way that works with a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
[self btnScore_Clicked:(id)sender];
```

with

```
[self btnScore_Clicked:self];
```

inside your `-init` implementation since you shouldn’t list argument types when sending a message to an object. Also, in that case, the sender of the `btnScore_Clicked:` action is the object itself, hence the `sender` parameter is `self`.

Furthermore,

```
numberTotal = 0;
```

is not necessary since all instance variables are zeroed out when a new instance is created.

Comment: @seaworthy Besides a missing `}` to close the `-init` method implementation, I don’t see why it shouldn’t work. Did you get any compiler error? What’s the output when you run your program?

Comment: the actual program is actually longer... When I press a button it loads an XML parser and populates some fields. So with your fix I was hoping that the fields would be populated right away when the program loads because the class tells it to press that button. What happens is, you have blank fields and you still need to press the button to populate them. In the above, program I would expect console to print <Number total: 1> and when I press the button <Number total: 2>.

Comment: @seaworthy If you’re using UI elements then you should not be doing this in `-init` because the view hasn’t been loaded from the nib file yet, hence you can’t populate any UI fields. A better place for this would be `-viewDidLoad`.